# Entry point of different languages

Tags: c, assembly, programming-languages, entry-point

I know that in C/C++ and Java, the entry point of a program is the function `main()`,
now I have the following two questions,

1. What's the program's entry point written in MASM, NASM, and other languages?
2. What's the convention from which CPU knows where to find entry point of a program?

==-EDIT-==

Question 2 is not a meaningful question since it is wrong that CPU takes responsibility of finding the entry point. There is no such convention. See `Eric Lippert`'s clarification.

Comment: By "MASM, NASM, and other languages" do you mean other Assembly languages or all other programming languages? If you mean the latter, this may be too broad.

Comment: C++ entry point may be prior to main (global object construction).

Comment: If you have two questions please post two questions. Don't ask two questions in the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In assembly (both MASM and NASM are merely assemblers, i.e. programs that convert assembly source code to machine code) there is no default entrypoint. You typically specify it with an assembler directive.

- With NASM, you use the [`.start`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.4.6) directive to place the entrypoint.
- With MASM it seems more complicated, but the [`end`](http://www.oocities.org/codeteacher/x86asm/asml1001.html) directive is important.

The address referenced then ends up in the binary (executable) file's header, so that the operating system can figure out where to jump.

For [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binaries (used on many operating systems) see the [`e_entry`](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/1998-04-29/ch4.eheader.html) header field:

> `e_entry`
>
> This member gives the virtual address to which the system first transfers control, thus starting the process. If the file has no associated entry point, this member holds zero.

This happens with C too, except there of course the compiler sits between your source and the executable file, so it inserts the required reference to `main()` (or, actually, typically to an init routine that runs before `main()`.

Java does not work with raw binaries, its programs on a JVM, so it doesn't really compare.

Comment: Your answer is clear, but further more, if I write various of functions in an assembly source file, how can I tell the compiler the entry point?

Answer (score 2):

The entry point is not usually defined by the compiler, but by the linker. See for example `ld --entry` for GCC or `link /ENTRY:` for VC++.

In C and C++, the default entry point is usually in the standard library (`_start` in GCC IIRC) and that function eventually calls the user `main()`.

Java, having the JVM, the program entry point is hard coded in the JVM.

If you program in assembly, it depens on whether you use some language's standard library:

- If you use the standard C library, add a `main()` function to your program, and all will just work as in C.
- If you do not use the standard C library, choose your own entry point and pass its name to the linker. Alternatively, you can name your entry point with the default name for your os (`_start`).

For example, compare the error messages of these two commands, when compiling and linking an empty C file:

```
$ gcc empty.c
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc -nostdlib empty.c
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000080480b8
```

You can change the entry name with:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -Wl,-entry,begin empty.c
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol begin; defaulting to 00000000080480b8
```

Comment: You mean the real entry point in C/C++ is _start? So is `_start` defined in `stdio.h`?

Comment: @user3505816: No, I mean that using the GCC toolchain in Linux, the default real entry point is `_start`. It is _defined_ in `crt1.o`, but you will not find it in `stdio.h` as it does not need to be _declared_ anywhere (you don't want to call it). In C and C++, the user-visible entry point is `main()`.

Comment: @user3505816 What usually happens is taht `_start` sets up the execution environment and then calls `main` from which the actual C or C++ code begins. As user unwind's answer states, the actual execution of the program starts at the entrypoint defined by the executable format, and in the case of ELF the `e_entry` points to the address of `_start`.

Comment: @rodrigo Can I understand it this way, `crt1.o` is a GCC-produced object file which contains the entry point `_start` and is to be linked with user-produced object file. When linking files, the linker will add something like `invoke main` right after `_start`.

Comment: @user3505816: Almost... `crt1.o` is a precompiled object file. Its source file, (say `crt1.c`) contains something along the lines of `void _start() { _init_crt(); int e = main(...); exit(e); };`, so the call to `main()` is not created by the linker, it is already there. The linker is just trying to solve the reference.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the convention from which CPU knows where to find entry point of a program?

The question cannot be answered because it presupposes a falsehood. There is no such convention *for the CPU*, because it's not the *CPU* that analyzes and runs an executable. It's the operating system that does that. How it does so depends on the format of the executable file. For example, in 16 bit MSDOS programs using the MZ file format the 15th and 16th bytes of the file contain the starting value for the instruction pointer. MSDOS can use this information when instructing the CPU what code it should execute.